# How to pass SwiftUI View as function parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, protocols

I want to show SwiftUI `View`s as subview of a `UIViewController`.  These views must implement a protocol.

I have this:

```
protocol ContentViewProtocol : View
{
    var values: [CGFloat] { get }
}

...

import SwiftUI

struct SearchContentView : ContentViewProtocol
{
    var values: [CGFloat] = [0.5, 0.7]

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

...

func showContent(view: ContentViewProtocol) <=== ERROR
{
    var child = UIHostingController(rootView: view) <=== SAME ERROR

    ...
}
```

I get the following error: `Protocol 'ContentViewProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

I get the same error when using a plain `View` as function parameter type (so with `func showContent(view: View)`).

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what the error says, and use `ContentViewProtocol` as a generic constraint. Make `showContent` generic:

```
func showContent<V: ContentViewProtocol>(view: V)
{
    let child = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    ...
}
```